# Guides for Spring MVC 2.5 or 3

Tags: java, spring-mvc

Am I alone in inability to find any guide for building Spring 2.5/3 MVC web applications or what?

I don't know what is going wrong with Spring docs, it became worst since VMWare acquired SpringSource.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There's this tutorial:

http://static.springframework.org/docs/Spring-MVC-step-by-step/index.html

I didn't find it really good but maybe you think different. I've commented about it [in this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76764/where-can-i-find-a-good-introductory-tutorial-for-spring/88026#88026).

So far, [Spring in Action](http://www.manning.com/walls3/) has been the best resource I've found for Spring.

Comment: That tutorial doesn't cover Spring 2.5 Convention-over-Configuration.
I don't want to read any thing relates to Spring 2 MVC when there was a tons of controllers to extend.
Now I understand why Java web developer flock to Rails or Django.

Answer (score 1):

[Try this one instead.](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html)

I'm not sure what you mean by "Spring 2.5 Convention-over-Configuration" though, I've really never heard that in the context of Spring, Maven on the other hand...but Spring?? Spring's all ABOUT configuration, whether done in XML or annotations. Its one of the things that kept me from seriously using Spring until annotations became a good solution...

I refuse to be an "XML Programmer". ;)

Comment: This Spring MVC 3 official page is hardly a guide, to me it is nothing more than highlights.

Answer (score 1):

http://jeromejaglale.com/doc/java/spring

This is the best I've come across: it's clear and simple, unlike many of the other tutorials out there. It's only a starting point, since it covers just a few aspects of Spring MVC, but a very good one nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

Many of the examples out there involve Maven - which has it's own learning curve, and complicates understanding the essentials of Spring.

What's nice about this tutorial http://jeromejaglale.com/doc/java/spring mentioned by Shane is that there is no added friction in having to get maven to play nice - Thanks Jerome!

Comment: I don't have a problem with Maven

Comment: [Article describing issues to consider when working with Maven](http://nealford.com/memeagora/2013/01/22/why_everyone_eventually_hates_maven.html)